Why does clang takes over my AdaptiveCpp(its similar to gcc) compiler?
I have installed Adaptive Cpp (acpp) on my Mac terminal and it compiled and installed as it should but while checking app --version, clang takes over acpp and it displays the version of clang rather than app. How should I solve this problem?
I tried adding alias in ./zshrc file. Also tried to specify the path but it didn't work.

this is expected behavior.
AdaptiveCpp extends an existing clang/LLVM installation with its own functionality. For various reasons (e.g. to not confuse build systems that attempt to detect clang-like compilers from --version) it follows the convention that all AdaptiveCpp flags have the --acpp-* prefix, while all other flags are left to the underlying clang/LLVM to handle.
So you want to use acpp --acpp-version to check for the AdaptiveCpp version, and --version to check for the underlying default AdaptiveCpp host compiler (typically clang).
The one exception to the convention I mentioned above is acpp --help, which will give you the AdaptiveCpp help output, which also explains the command line flag handling behavior.
